# How to make a server/srr render only as vue components?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using `vue-no-ssr` (https://github.com/egoist/vue-no-ssr), but it creates components that only render on the client side. I want to render my component on the server side. Is there any way to make a vue component that only renders on the server?

I tried to use the source code of `vue-no-ssr` below, but I don't understand how to adept it.

```
export default {
  name: 'NoSsr',
  functional: true,
  props: {
    placeholder: String,
    placeholderTag: {
      type: String,
      default: 'div'
    }
  },
  render(h, { parent, slots, props }) {
    const { default: defaultSlot = [], placeholder: placeholderSlot } = slots()

    if (parent._isMounted) {
      return defaultSlot
    }

    parent.$once('hook:mounted', () => {
      parent.$forceUpdate()
    })

    if (props.placeholderTag && (props.placeholder || placeholderSlot)) {
      return h(
        props.placeholderTag,
        {
          class: ['no-ssr-placeholder']
        },
        props.placeholder || placeholderSlot
      )
    }

    // Return a placeholder element for each child in the default slot
    // Or if no children return a single placeholder
    return defaultSlot.length > 0 ? defaultSlot.map(() => h(false)) : h(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more clear what I think you wanted to ask. I must say however that it does not make much sense to me why you would want to have SSR-only components though. If you use SSR, everything is server-rendered, **unless you navigate in the application**. An SSR-only component would just be some kind of placeholder until you refresh... unless you make your navigation a static link in which case any work you do on a SSR-only component is not needed.

Comment: @Sumurai8  i wanna make something like it will not display in client mode, only when use ssr will render it, or wehn use client mode, that render context wil not update by client, will display as prerender context from ssr

Answer (score 0):

vue-lazy-hydration

https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration

looks like can do ssr-only when-idle when-visible ... and more